# combine nodes in many-to-many relation

Tags: xslt

I have an xml snippet with a many-to-many relation through id attributes, an example would be like so:

```
<root>
  <foolist name="firstlist">
    <foo barid="1" someval="some"/>
    <foo barid="1" someval="other"/>
    <foo barid="2" someval="third"/>
  </foolist>
  <foolist name="secondlist">
  <!-- there might be more foo's here that reference the same
       bars, so foo can't be a child of bar -->
  </foolist>
  <bar id="1" baz="baz" qux="qux"/>
  <bar id="2" bax="baz2" qux="qux2"/>
</root>
```

Say I want to get out the following:

```
baz-some-qux
baz-other-qux
baz2-third-qux2
```

(that is, insert the value of someval between the values of baz and qux from the referenced item), how should I do this? If I want to use a template for bar, I would need two different ones. I'm probably missing something really basic here, so my apologies in advance.

(EDIT: expanded example)

Comment: Martijn, You might be interested in a more efficient, key-based solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="foo">
      <xsl:variable name="matchingBar" select="../../bar[@id = current()/@barid]" />
      <xsl:value-of select="concat($matchingBar/@baz, '-', ./@someval, '-', $matchingBar/@qux, '&#xA0;')" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! Not every foo element should be processed for each bar element. I'll expand my question a little to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

**An efficient solution, using keys**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kFooById" match="foo" use="@barid"/>

 <xsl:template match="bar">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kFooById', @id)" mode="refer">
    <xsl:with-param name="pReferent" select="."/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="foo" mode="refer">
  <xsl:param name="pReferent" select="/.."/>

  <xsl:value-of select=
   "concat($pReferent/@baz,'-',@someval,'-',$pReferent/@qux,'&#xA;')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (corrected for well-formedness):

```
<root>
  <foolist name="firstlist">
    <foo barid="1" someval="some"/>
    <foo barid="1" someval="other"/>
    <foo barid="2" someval="third"/>
  </foolist>
  <foolist name="secondlist">
  <!-- there might be more foo's here that reference the same
       bars, so foo can't be a child of bar -->
  </foolist>
  <bar id="1" baz="baz" qux="qux"/>
  <bar id="2" baz="baz2" qux="qux2"/>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
baz-some-qux
baz-other-qux
baz2-third-qux2
```